# Do maven plugin for eclipse have maven software bundled?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-3

For creating maven projects withing Eclipse IDE, we use maven plugin for eclipse (m2e).

My doubt is does this plugin have the "maven software / binaries" bundled? Usually when we want to create a maven project from command line (without any IDE), we manually install the maven (from site http://maven.apache.org ), that is the maven binaries. In case of maven plugin for eclipse we don't download maven binaries, we simply download the plugin. So my question is, does maven plugin for eclipse have the "maven binaries" in-built?

Any help in understanding this would be of great help.

**Update**

Based on the response I checked in eclipse and this is what I can see:

[image]

So I believe the "EMBEDDED" is the one which comes as part of the maven-plugin for eclipse. If this is the case, then where do we see its configuration details?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it usually includes an "embedded" installation (embedded within quotes because I think it is not similar to the standard installation -- e.g. no `mvn` batch or shell scripts like the out-of-box installation). Also the plugin is available by default in Eclipse starting Mars version (4.5). You can verify this by checking the installation from the preference: **Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations**.

As for the settings, this can also be checked in the preferences by selecting **Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings**. There it indicates the path to the settings.xml and the local repository path inferred from those settings.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, helpful indeed. I have one more question which is in the update section. Can you please help me understand?

Comment: @CuriousMind If by configuration you mean settings.xml, then it's also shown in the prefs.

Comment: Yes, the setting which it would take from where to download the dependencies. I did check the location (by default, .m2/setting.xml), but this file was not there. So my doubt is how come it is able to download the dependencies, because there is NO setting.xml (which tells about repo url ). Is it something which is "hard-coded" in plugin's code?